# Converting time object time to datetime and converting the datetime to values

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

Hi Im currently working with a dataset from IEX and cant seem to convert the time to a value that I can work with.

I looped through the dataframe and converted the values to datetime

```
for i, row in enumerate(df['label']):
df['date'][i]=datetime.strptime(df['label'][i], format)
```

which gave me a new column but I can only access the hour/minute if I index it `df['label'][1].hour`

when I try to loop through again to pull the values to I get a keyerror: Time

```
for i, row in enumerate(df['date']):
df['Time'][i]=((df['date'][i].hour -9)*60 +df['date'][i].minute)
```

Comment: Can you show the DataFrame ?

Comment: df=pd.read_json('https://api.iextrading.com/1.0/stock/'+sym+'/chart/1d')    sym=SPY , Im note sure how to upload it on here

Comment: Unnamed: 0 average changeOverTime close date high label low marketAverage marketChangeOverTime ... marketLow marketNotional marketNumberOfTrades marketOpen marketVolume minute notional numberOfTrades open volume
0 0 272.448 0.000000 272.510 1900-01-01 09:30:00 272.600 09:30 AM 272.350 272.477 0.000000 ... 272.350 3.659716e+08 2223 272.420 1343127 09:30 3403698.495 58 272.420 12493
1 1 272.435 -0.000048 272.370 1900-01-01 09:31:00 272.500 09:31 AM 272.370 272.450 -0.000099 ... 272.350 6.114483e+07 1532 272.530 224426 09:31 211136.750 9 272.500 775
2

Comment: I am trying to do something like this   'for i, row in enumerate(df['date']):
    df['Time']=(((df['date'][i].hour-9)*60)+df['date'][i].minute)
df['Time']' . but it updates all the rows to the last minute 3:59=419

Answer (score 0):

This worked in ipython notebook using Python3

```
import json
import pandas as pd
from pandas import *
import datetime

convert_hour = lambda x: datetime.datetime.strptime(x , '%H:%M %p').strftime('%H') if len(x) > 5 else datetime.datetime.strptime(x , '%I %p').strftime('%H')
df['hour'] = df['label'].apply(convert_hour)
convert_minute = lambda x: datetime.datetime.strptime(x , '%H:%M %p').strftime('%M') if len(x) > 5 else 0
df['minute2'] = df['label'].apply(convert_minute)
```

Comment: I keep getting type object 'datetime.datetime' has no attribute 'datetime' on jupyter notebook python3

Comment: Hey JJ See the edit. I mistakenly left out the packages I imported.

Comment: Lol that makes sense, I found the answer thanks to your code.

Comment: Glad I could kinda help LOL

Answer (score 0):

Thank you guys for you support I found the answer

for i, row in enumerate(df['date']):
    df['label'][i]=(((df['date'][i].hour-9)*60)+df['date'][i].minute)